# FBGraphUser in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fb-graph

I'm using the Facebook iOS SDK in Swift to access Facebook and I would like to work with the [`FBGraphUser`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphUser/) (or [`FBGraphPlace`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphPlace/), [`FBGraphLocation`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphLocation/))  protocols rather than with a pure `Dictionary`. The request completes successfully but I cannot cast the result to the `FBProtocol`

```
FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
     // this does not work
    if let fbGraphUser = result as? FBGraphUser {
        NSLog("\(fbGraphUser)")
    }

     // this works
    if let fbGraphUserDict = result as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
        println("\(fbGraphUserDict)")
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to unwrap the optionals to get the FBxxxx objects ?

cheers